# Выскакивает InvalidOperationException при присоединении DataSet к DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

Есть `DataGridView`, он присоединен к `SQLite`. При изменении БД вручную через запросы, пытаюсь изменить в режиме реального времени таблицу и отобразить на ней новые значения строк. И в месте, где я присоединяю `DataSet` к своей `DataGridView`, возникает данное исключение. Причем, исключение возникает не всегда, а после какого-то уже изменения или еще чего, сам точно это не поняд. Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как можно решить данную проблему?

```
con.Open();
sql = "select rowid, * from OpenPos";
adapOpenPos = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con);
dsOpenPos = new DataSet();
adapOpenPos.Fill(dsOpenPos);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsOpenPos.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
con.Close();
```

---

Ошибка:

> Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления, не из того потока, в котором он был создан.

Comment: Уберите из запроса `rowid`

Comment: Укажите полное сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Ошибка - Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления, не из того потока, в котором он был создан.

Answer (score 1):

Данная проблема решается несколькими способами :

.NET не позволяет обращаться к контролам напрямую из других потоков.

**Простой и неправильный способ :**
Отменяем проверку, из какого потока используется контрол

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Для одного раза может и сработать, но делать так крайне не рекомендуется.

**Использование методов Invoke/BeginInvoke**

Эти методы выполняют указанные делегаты в том потоке, в котором контрол был создан.
Invoke вызывает делегат синхронно, BeginInvoke - асинхронно.
Чтобы определить, требуется ли Invoke используйте свойство InvokeRequired.
Например, объявляем делегат

```
delegate void Del(string text);
```

и вызываем Invoke

```
textBox1.Invoke(new Del((s) => textBox1.Text = s), "newText");
```

Вместо объявления новых делегатов можно использовать готовые, Action или Func
Пример готового, потоко-безопасного метода

```
void SetTextSafe(string newText)
{
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired) 
         textBox1.Invoke(new Action<string>((s) => textBox1.Text = s), newText);
    else 
         textBox1.Text = newText;
}
```

Ссылка на оригинал
http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread513431.html

Comment: Если вы копируете ответ из другого источника, то неплохо бы из благодарности к авторам исходного сообщения оставить [ссылку на оригинал](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-cli-winforms/thread1812800.html#a_CrossThread).